# new Date("6/18/2014") !== new Date("6/18/2014")

Tags: javascript

```
new Date("6/18/2014") !== new Date("6/18/2014");
```

returns true

```
new Date("6/18/2014") === new Date("6/18/2014");
```

returns false

moment(datestring) returns the same as above.  How can this be and what is wront with the date comparisons.

Comment: you are comparing references.

Comment: sorry for lack of research.  Thanks for the advice